# Series of non-zero rational terms converging to a rational number?

Tags: sequences-and-series

On a recent test, I was asked if the following statement was true or false:

*Every convergent series of non-zero rational terms converges to an irrational number*

I marked it as false because I don't see why this would be true, but I couldn't think of a counterexample. Is this statement True or False? Can you provide a proof or counter example?

Comment: $1+1/2+1/4+\cdots=2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement is false.

Counter-example:

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(n+1)}$$

$$ = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1}$$

$$= 1.$$

Or a simpler counter example: any geometric series with $|r| < 1$.

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun, here’s another way of constructing counterexamples.

Let $\langle r_k:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ be any sequence of non-zero rationals converging to $0$. For $k\in\Bbb N$ let $a_{2k}=r_k$ and $a_{2k+1}=-r_k$; clearly $a_k$ is rational for all $k\in\Bbb N$. Moreover, for $n\in\Bbb N$ we have

$$\sum_{k=0}^{2n}a_k=r_n\qquad\text{and}\qquad\sum_{k=0}^{2n+1}a_k=0\;,$$

so

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^na_k=0\;,$$

and $\displaystyle\sum_{k\ge 0}a_k=0$ is rational.

The idea admits any number of variations. For instance, if $\langle p_k:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ and $\langle q_k:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ are bounded sequences of positive rationals, you can let

$$\begin{align*}
a_{3k}&=p_kr_k\;,\\
a_{3k+1}&=q_kr_k\;,\text{ and}\\
a_{3k+2}&=-(p_k+q_k)r_k
\end{align*}$$

for each $k\in\Bbb N$, and you’ll still have $\sum_{k\ge 0}a_k=0$.